React Native Webview reloading on Orientation Change
I am trying to create a video viewer for Youtube and Vimeo for an app on iOS and Android with the following RN-component:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import WebView from 'react-native-autoheight-webview';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export const VideoPlayer = ({videoId, type}: any) => {

  const win = Dimensions.get('window');
  
  return (
    (type=="vimeo") ?
    <>    
    <WebView
      allowsFullscreenVideo
      scrollEnabled={false}
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets
      style={{ width: win.width, height: win.height,  flex: 1 }}
      source={{
        html: `<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/${videoId}" width="${win.width}" height="${win.height}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`
      }}
    />
    </>
    :
    <>       
    <WebView
      allowsFullscreenVideo
      scrollEnabled={false}
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets
      style={{ width: win.width, height: win.height,  flex: 1 }}
      source={{
        html: `<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}" frameborder="0" referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" ></iframe>`
      }}
    />
    </>
  );
}

export default VideoPlayer

This works, but an orientation change from portrait to landscape and vice versa causes the Webview to reload and the running video stops and everything is back to the beginning.
Is there any way of telling the webview not to reload on orientation-change?
Thanks for any hints in advance!

try using WebView from react-native-webview I have used same code with react-native-webview it works fine without any reload.
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';


OK, the issue was that the Component was inside a SwiperFlatList, without that, the Webview does not reload and the video continues playing.
